# Ruby code in Gemfile isn't executed

Tags: ruby, rack, roda

In my Roda app I have this:

```
# Gemfile

puts "env is: " + ENV["RACK_ENV"]

if ENV["RACK_ENV"] == "development"
  puts "env dev"
  gem "gem1"
end
```

This isn't working: the "puts" aren't executed, and the gem "gem1" isn't included either. The "env" is development, I've checked that when a page is loading.

Why not and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is to set gems based on their environment, you use groups in the Gemfile.

You can do some thing like this...

```
# A sample Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'roda'
gem 'haml'

# This is the group for development environment
group :development do
  # gem 'shotgun'
  gem 'gem1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'byebug'
end
```

Coming back to your question...

I assume you haven't set the `RACK_ENV` variable. I don't develop Roda but I think it is just assuming it is 'development'. So if you want to use `RACK_ENV` variable in your code, you will need to set it explicitly.

You can do an `export RACK_ENV=development` to set the env explicitly.

Comment: there're 2!!!!!! puts in my Gemfile **puts "env is: " + ENV["RACK_ENV"]** the 1st one should execute always

Comment: @Koodi: I know it was Rack/Roda

Comment: @Koodi: Gemfile is a means bundler uses to manage Ruby gems, decide what to install. I suggest you do some reading: http://bundler.io/gemfile.html

Comment: I said **there're 2 puts in my Gemfile puts "env is: " + ENV["RACK_ENV"] the 1st one should execute always –** -- read my question

Answer (score 1):

> the "puts" aren't executed, and the gem "gem1" isn't included either.

Actually, this proves that your Ruby code *is* executed correctly. If you run `bundle install` or `rackup` or `rails s`, the environment variable `RACK_ENV` is not set, so `ENV['RACK_ENV']` is `nil`.

Comment: you don't notice " puts "env is: " + ENV["RACK_ENV"]" or what?

Comment: What was printed then?